# Is there is a way for me to host my express api on the internet?

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have recently started learning MERN stack and I made my first front-end application using React and I connected it using an API that I have created using Express. It works perfectly fine on my local machine using localhost.

But whenever I try to upload it to a hosting service, like Heroku for example, it gives me a 404 error whenever I open the link. Is there is a way for me to upload my API into a hosting service for free or is there is something I'm doing wrong in my code ?

```js
    const express = require('express');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const cors = require('cors');
    const app = express();
    require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname + '/.env' });
    const URI = process.env.URI;
    mongoose.connect(URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: true });
    const connection = mongoose.connection;
    connection.once('once', () => {
      console.log('connection to database has been initiated sucessfully');
    });
    const itemRouter = require('./routes/itemsRouter.js');
    const orderRouter = require('./routes/orderRouter.js');
    const mailRouter = require('./routes/mailRouter.js');
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(cors());
    app.use('/items', itemRouter);
    app.use('/orders', orderRouter);
    app.use('/sendMail', mailRouter);
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`App is running on port ${PORT}`);
    });
```

Comment: heroku should work. are you following the heroku express docs? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs

Comment: wow... thanks bro it actually worked thank you , all i did is just clone the git repo that they are including and i put my project inside of it and committed the changes and pushed it and it worked perfectly i just.. don't understand why and what happened giving that i didn't do it before with any of my front-end projects just static website , but really thank you ;D

Answer (score 1):

Heroku should work out the box if you've followed the setup here [Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#deploy-the-app).

However, if you're using freshly shipped ubuntu or similar server. You'll need to set up the environment by doing the following:

- Install node run time, nginx & a node deamon manager (In this case PM2)

  - `sudo apt install nodejs nginx`
  - `npm install -g pm2`
- Create an nginx config

  ```
  server {
    listen 80;
    index index.html;
    server_name YOUR_DOMAIN/SERVER_IP;

    location / {
      proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:NODE_BOUND_PORT;
    }
  }
  ```
- Deamonise the Node script

  - `pm2 start index.js`

You'll have to restart nginx and create the symbolic links for NGINX to pick up the routing but once this is done, should route as intended.